# Prove that $~~~~~a_1!a_2!\cdots a_m! \mid \left(a_1+a_2+...+a_m\right)! ~~~~~~~~~\forall ~~~a_1,a_2,...,a_m\in N$

Tags: induction, factorial

Show that $$a_1!a_2!\cdots a_m! \mid \left(a_1+a_2+...+a_m\right)! \forall a_1,a_2,...,a_m\in N$$

---

**Case 1** $m=2$. We  need to prove $$a_1!a_2!\mid (a_1+a_2)!$$

1. $a_1+a_2=1$ and $a_1+a_2=2$. It is obvious
2. $a+b=n (n\in \text{N  and } a+b\le n).$

We will prove in $$a+b=n+1$$

By assuming of the induction $$(a_1!(a_2-1)!)\mid(a_1+a_2-1)!$$

And $$(a_2!(a_1-1)!)\mid(a_1+a_2-1)!$$

$$\rightarrow (a_1!a_2!)\mid (a_1+a_2)(a_1+a_2-1)!$$

Or $$\rightarrow (a_1!a_2!)\mid (a_1+a_2)!$$

**Case 2** $m=k$

We will prove in $m=k+1$

I am stuck here. Can I prove it as with the case $m = 2?$, help me.

Comment: If you are allowed to use a combinatorial proof, you can argue that ${(a_1+\cdots+a_m)!\over a_1!\dots a_m!}$ is the number of ways to distribute $a_1+\cdots+a_m$ distinct objects into $m$ labeled bins, with $a_i$ objects in bin $i$ for $1=1,\dots,m$.

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry I dont know what is combinatorial proof.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Thank you. It was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the $m=2$ case:
$$
a_1!(a_2+\ldots+a_{n+1})!\,\vert\, (a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n+1})!,
$$
and by the inductive hypothesis for $m=n$,
$$
a_2!\ldots a_{n+1}!\vert (a_2+\ldots+a_{n+1})!.
$$
Putting these together gives the $n+1$ case.